# Calling Access Interop function that returns UDT from VB.NET code throws error

Tags: vba, ms-access, com, interop

I have a Microsoft Access 2000 database. There is a module with a type declared:

```
Type MyTestType
    Something As String
End Type
```

There is also a function that returns the above type:

```
Function MyTestFunction() As MyTestType    
    Dim a As MyTestType        
    MyTestFunction = a    
End Function
```

I am trying to automate the calling of the function from a .NET 4.0 Console Application using VB.NET. I have a method as follows:

```
Sub ProcessAccessFunction()
    Dim access As New ApplicationClass()

    Try
        access.OpenCurrentDatabase("c:\MyTestFolder\MyTestDatabase.mdb", False)
        Dim result = access.Run("MyTestFunction")
    Finally
        access.Quit(AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone)
    End Try
End Sub
```

However, I receive an error saying "The value does not fall within the expected range". What do I need to do to receive the object successfully in my VB.NET app?

Answer (score 0):

User Defined Types are pretty limited in VBA.
For instance, from within Access itself, you can't do this:

```
?TypeName(Application.Run("MyTestTypeFunction"))
```

You will get a *Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument*.
The visibility of a UDF is very limited, so much so that it is not visible to the outside world at all.
`Application.Run` uses OLE Automation to execute the function call. Since your UDF is only known within the confines of your database and not exported anywhere, no type information is available to the external world, and using it from `Application.Run` will fail, within access itself and by extension when calling from .Net.

If your function was just returning a string, it would work perfectly.

Comment: I am aware returning a string works. Is there any way to export the UDTs so that my .NET app knows about them?

Comment: @CamronBute, as far as I know, no. It's probably possible to hack and pass raw memory data that you cast to a type already defined in your .Net app, but it's probably going to be quite complicated and brittle and will take you probably more effort than it is worth. You can try to "serialize" data into a string and recompose that data in your .Net object/VBA code, but you will be passing copies only, and it's going to be inefficient.